# rdesktop: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: arch-linux, rdesktop

I installed `rdesktop` via `pacman` (package manager)
After that I tried runned `rdesktop` command for connect to remote windows' desktop
and got that error

```
rdesktop: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libpcsclite.so.1: file too short
```

I tried install `libpcsclite` package via `pacman` and `yaourt` but they didn't find the package.

The question is how to fix that issue?

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 3):

A [quick search](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/pcsclite/files/) turned up that the `libpcsclite.so.1` file is a part of `pcsclite 1.8.16-1`.

Try installing that package. If it still isn't found update pacman with:

`pacman -Syu`

and try again. If it's still not working you may not have the correct mirrors setup.

Comment: Excellent mate, glad to hear! Would you mind accepting the answer so that others will know at a glance that the problem is solved?